# Command prompt how to exclude windows partition using for loop

Tags: command-line, batch, cmd.exe

I want to list all windows partitions and then exclude partition in which window is installed like (C:\ , it can be any letter) here is command to list partitions

```
for /f "skip=1 delims=" %x in ('wmic logicaldisk get caption') do @echo.%x
```

**output:**

```
D:
E:
C:
M:
X:
Y:
```

and here is command to find partition in which windows is installed

```
for /f "tokens=1 delims=\" %i in ('echo %userprofile%') do @echo %i
```

**output:**

```
C:
```

is there any for loop command to list all partitions **excluding windows partition** and can output like this

```
D:
E:
M:
X:
Y:
```

Comment: User profiles can be on a different drive than the system.  If you want to know where Windows is installed, it may be better to use`%SystemRoot%` (or `%SystemDrive%`) rather than ``%UserProfile%``).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid `Caption`, `%SystemDrive%` and *additional extra spaces after every letter* using `^|findstr/v "Cap %SystemDrive%"` in your loop command, and remove `Skip=1 Delims=`:

```
for /f %i in ('wmic logicaldisk get caption^|findstr/v "Cap %SystemDrive%"')do @echo\%i
```

Comment: This seems to perform quicker than the other answer in my testing.

Comment: @DrinkSomePimpJuiceIT Thanks for your comment. It is slower takes a look here **[look here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TWdT.png)**

Comment: I don't see the whole command in that screen shot but for my system without the actual time measuring tool on my system, the command you provided appears to show all the multiple drive letters a little quicker than the other answer. It is most certainly quicker than the below command in my system that I can tell for the entire command to process all drives.

Answer (score 3):

```
for /f "skip=1 delims=" %x in ('wmic logicaldisk get caption') do @echo.%x | find /v "%userprofile:~0,2%"
```

Comment: ```for /f "skip=1 delims=" %x in ('wmic logicaldisk get caption') do @echo.%x | find /v "%userprofile:~0,2%" >> output.txt```
there is some extra spaces after every letter can we remove??

Comment: @Sadam - In the delims part you are selecting the whole line from WMIC which has trailing spaces. Change it to this  `"skip=1 delims= "`

Comment: Or just leave off the ```delims=``` option altogether.